# could not locate setShippingMethod function in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I have enabled table rate shipping methods in magento. This is my checkout page [image]

This is the action of update total button

action="http://{{site-url}}/checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost/"

Now when I go to estimateUpdatePost action in cartcontroller.php file there is a line

```
   if (!empty($code)) {
        $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($code)/*->collectTotals()*/->save();
    }
```

I am lookin for setShippingMethod($code) function. I had look through the files in magento and found this function in these two files

\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Model\Sales\Order\Create.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart\Shipping\Api.php

But when I put die on setShippingMethod function and try to echo something then it is not shown and the page loads. It means these two setShippingMethod function is not hit and there is a function setShippingMethod somewhere else that is hit, due to which code runs. I want to locate it or if setShippingMethod function is not hit then anyone could tell me how update total button action is working.

I have made some changes to my code. 
First made changes to estimateUpdatePost action

```
   public function estimateUpdatePostAction()
{
    $code = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_method');

    if (!empty($code)) {
        $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($code)/*->collectTotals()*/->save();
        die('ssssss');
    }
    $this->_goBack();
}
```

and then looked for setData function in magento. Found this function in following files
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Abstract.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Centinel\Model\StateAbstract.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Log\Adapter.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Zend.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Dataflow\Model\Convert\Container\Abstract.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Widget\Block\Interface.php

I had put a die with a message in all these functions, and when I clicked on update total button, 'ssssss' this message is shown on browser, means no setData function is running. 
I am really stuck in this. Please help me in getting part of code that runs setShippingMethod($code) in estimateUpdatePostAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address** class

Although you won't find it as a function, because `setShippingMethod` is an alias for `setData('shipping_method')`, which just sets shipping method code in the address

So the function you are searching in this case would be `setData()` in **Varien_Object** class

```
/**
 * Overwrite data in the object.
 *
 * $key can be string or array.
 * If $key is string, the attribute value will be overwritten by $value
 *
 * If $key is an array, it will overwrite all the data in the object.
 *
 * @param string|array $key
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
public function setData($key, $value=null)
{
    $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
    if(is_array($key)) {
        $this->_data = $key;
        $this->_addFullNames();
    } else {
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
        if (isset($this->_syncFieldsMap[$key])) {
            $fullFieldName = $this->_syncFieldsMap[$key];
            $this->_data[$fullFieldName] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I have made some changes to my question according to your answer.Please have a look.

Comment: I think my answer would be the same, if I understand what you are asking

Comment: You said setData function is used. So I put a die on setData function then why that die message is not showing when update total button is clicked.

Comment: Have you validated "estimate_method" is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code for set Shipping method,it is working well to me.

```
$this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                  ->setFreeShipping(1)
                  ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
```

You can use this code.

if Free shipping, `setFreeShipping()` as 1 otherwise 0.

Comment: I used this code $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                  ->setFreeShipping(0)
                  ->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway')
      ->save(); but not working

Comment: is shipping method "tablerate_bestway" enabled for that store.?

Comment: yes, it's enabled

Comment: I was headed in the wrong direction. Actually the problem was one of the modules. Disabled it and everything is working fine

Comment: Did you find what problem in that module.?

Comment: No I just disabled that module, was not needed. But now will look for the problem in the module after completing my task as I have to deliver it.